# How to add classes to a list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, collections, entity-framework-plus

If i have a set of Entities (Classes) like this :

```
Employee, Department, Room ... etc
```

---

How to add these **classes** to a list instead of a list of objects :

Like this :

```
{Employee, Department, Room}
```

---

I want to get these classes because i have a method with the following signature :

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<T>();
```

So How to loop on a list of classes and Pass them to this method e.g :

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<Employee>();
```

Comment: @MightyBadaboom : No i want to add the types not the objects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type> {typeof(Employee), typeof(Department), typeof(Room)};
```

Or you can get type from existed object:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type> {EmployeeInstance.GetType(), DepartmentInstance.GetType(), RoomInstance.GetType()};
```

---

I will try to explain difference between `Employee` and `typeof(Employee)` but better will be read [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx):

**Employee** it's like your *data contract*. It have fields like X and Y.

**typeof(Employee)** is your *type of 'contract'*, it have information about fields - information that contains a description about X and Y fields.

---

[MSDN: Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between `Employee` and `typeof(Employee)` please ?

Comment: see edited, but i not sure about that